# auto populating in text boxes in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I'm developing a project with jsp.

There are two text boxes on the page. If I select first text box i get the list of countries fetching from MySQL database, I have done it with jQuery. now the problem is:

with out any events(especially buttons) automatically in the 2nd TEXT BOX the states/cities should be populated.

Does anybody have any idea? I used most of the JavaScript events such as onselect, onclick, etc. but no use.

And I'm not supposed to use a dropdown list.

Comment: When the user select a value on the first combo u wanna fill the second filtering with that value?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .ajax or .get to get the list of countries from the database?
If you are, try using .getJSON instead. You can provide effectively an array of responses, therefore meaning your first response from the AJAX script data.countries and the second element in the json array is data.states.

jQuery

```
 $("#text-box").click(function(){
    $.getJSON('ajax/get-locations.jsp', function(data) {
      $('#div-countries').html(data.countries);
      $('#div-states').html(data.states);
    });
 });
```

JSP

```
// Query to get countries
// Build html for countries list (stored in $countriesHTML)

// Query to get states
// Build html for states list (stored in $statesHTML)

// Put html in json array and echo / print / output the json as the result of your script (in the below format, replace $countriesHTML and $statesHTML with your own variables for the HTML).

echo '{ "countries": $countriesHTML, "states": $statesHTML }'
```

I hope this makes sense, I've not done JSP in ages which is why I've not attempted to code it, but the above seudo-code should be the theory applicable to any scripting language.

Comment: THANKS FOR THE REPLY... BUT I USED JQUERY WITH JSP.. BUT I DONT KNOW JSON CAN U PLEASE PROVIDE ANY LINKS FOR TUTORIALS ABOUT IT

Comment: The javascript code above is jQuery, it's just using a function called .getJSON() as opposed to .get(). Instead of just printing the results from your JSP script, you would put the countries into one element of the JSON array and the states into the other (see above).

Below is a link to the jQuery info on .getJSON()
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/